# How to change the typeface of Chip view?

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-typeface

I would like to change the typeface of **Chip** view from design support library. After I explorer it's source code, I found that it draw the text in **ChipDrawable** directly by Paint and I can't find any public method to change the typeface. How should I try to change that Chip view typeface? Please help. Thanks you.

Answer (score 30):

It's a little late but I will post my solution in case someone is still interested.

First create a font family xml with your custom font.

```
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/my_custom_font"/>
</font-family>
```

Then add a chip style to your styles xml that uses your font family:

```
<style name="chipText" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Chip">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my_font_family</item>
</style>
```

Then, when you create your chip view in xml, set the textAppearance attribute:

```
android:textAppearance="@style/chipText"
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I load chips programmatically and chip view blinks as it first loads default font, and after that my font. With many chips, it doesn't look nice although it's the right font at the end. Does someone have a similar problem?

Comment: thanks it works, though setting typeface inside Chip directly doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
chip.typeface = Typeface.create(ResourcesCompat.getFont(this,R.font.segoe_ui),Typeface.NORMAL)
```

Answer (score 1):

your solution working normal chip view - it still has some issue chip inside TextInputLayout. (font not changing)

notes: after screen rotates custom font changed, I don't know why

implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01"

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/chipText"
        android:hint="Text Field">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/chipText"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```